# How to simplify this mass of similar ifs

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to simplify this piece of code. The logic for every if condition is basically the same so I want to get rid of the duplicate ifs:

```
      if "video_codec" in profile:
          self.video_codec = profile["video_codec"]
      if "resolution_width" in profile:
          self.resolution_width = profile["resolution_width"]
      if "resolution_height" in profile:
          self.resolution_height = profile["resolution_height"]
      if "ratio" in profile:
          self.ratio = profile["ratio"]
      if "video_bitrate" in profile:
          self.video_bitrate = profile["video_bitrate"]
      if "profile" in profile:
          self.profile = profile["profile"]
      if "audio_codec" in profile:
          self.audio_codec = profile["audio_codec"]
      if "audio_channels" in profile:
          self.audio_channels = profile["audio_channels"]
      if "audio_bitrate" in profile:
          self.audio_bitrate = profile["audio_bitrate"]
```

I hope this can be done in 3-4 lines instead of my 18 lines.

Comment: Are you wanting to go through all of the fields in `profile` and filling in the details as you catch them?  That might be a more 'ideal' way to address this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to copy all key/value pairs from `profile` to attributes in `self`, you can use the following:

```
self.__dict__.update(profile)
```

If there are some items in `profile` that you do not want to copy, then you can use the following:

```
for attr in ("video_codec", "resolution_width", "resolution_height", "video_bitrate", 
             "ratio", "profile", "audio_codec", "audio_channels", "audio_bitrate"):
    if attr in profile: 
        setattr(self, attr, profile[attr])
```

Answer (score 10):

```
for key, value in profile.iteritems():
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

Should do what you want

Comment: Or just update `self.__dict__` - single line of code and should be quicker to boost ;)

Comment: @voo but more ugly. Thou shall not screw with `__dict__`

Comment: If the profile contains keys you don't wish to capture, add an if statement: `if key in wanted_keys: setattr(self, key, value)`